# AndroidStudio - two identical (same sourcecode) apps - one works, second doesnt - app closes after starting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

after setting up a new development environment and just wanted to get started, I have two simple Android Apps with just an easy, normal ImageView. They have both the same sourcecode (title is different) and amazingly the first one works, the second doesnt.

**The second app gets closed instantly after beeing started. The first one works and shows the image.**
As the problem I could identify the ImageView, if I delete the element, the app is starting fine.

Maybe someone can give me a tip or can help. Thank you very much!

AndroidStudio 3.6 -
Device for testing: Huawei Android 6.0

MainActivity.java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void fade (View view){
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:onClick="fade"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bart" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
05-12 23:29:44.274 14433-14433/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-12 23:29:44.356 14433-14450/com.example.testdrei E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
05-12 23:29:44.373 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.testdrei-2/lib/arm64
05-12 23:29:44.401 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
05-12 23:29:44.412 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-12 23:29:44.477 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
05-12 23:29:44.477 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
05-12 23:29:44.559 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060061 (t=5 e=97) (error -75)
05-12 23:29:44.559 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060061 (t=5 e=97) (error -75)
05-12 23:29:44.592 14433-14433/com.example.testdrei I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14433 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You're gonna have to post the [stack trace from logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces) otherwise we're blind here.

Comment: Thank you. of Course, above you can find the Logcat after running the app which doesnt work. Thanks.

Comment: There's no stack trace, no exception. Is there anything else after the sigkill message (the last line)? Can you check build.gradle if there's any suspicious difference?

Answer (score 0):

The ImageView with ID `R.id.imageView3` is not a part of your layout. So the below line will cause an exception

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
```

Change it with the correct ID

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This was my mistake, the MainActivity.java is copied from App1, the activity_main.xml is copied from App2, the ids are correct. (Code above is edited now) As I said, App1 is working correct, App2 is starting for ~0.5 seconds. The picture is not shown, so I think the app does not launch the MainActivity at all.

Comment: @elJanno just see you updated your question.. feel free to ask if still have problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this first and lets see if the error is coming from the xml file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bart" />
```